# how to make EditText field grow horizontally instead of vertically in android app

Tags: android

I have an edittext field. As I type and characters exceed the maxlength of it there appears a new row to continue typing. However, I want to avoid this behavior since there is map below it which is going down relatively.

I don't want to restrict the maxlength as well.
Can someone explain how do I solve this problem?

Comment: I realized I am new to stackoverflow and don't have enough points to upload images.

Comment: You also need to share your XML layout code with us so that we can help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define following parameters in your xml under the edittext tag:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: then you can also accept the answer and mark it with upvote so that other user can get also benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if Im wrong, but is't singleLine="true" depricated?

```
android:lines="1"
```